# Battery Life calculation

Tags: batteries

I am doing some calculations to determine battery life under certain load conditions. As such I have turned to the internet and found [this online calculator by DigiKey](http://www.digikey.com/en/resources/conversion-calculators/conversion-calculator-battery-life). The calculator used the following equation:

> Battery Life = Battery Capacity in Milli amps per hour / Load Current in Mill amps * 0.70

My question is:

- What is the 0.7 scalar multiple on the equation for?
- how can i take into consideration battery internal leakage current into my calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [your own link](http://www.digikey.com/en/resources/conversion-calculators/conversion-calculator-battery-life):

> *The factor of 0.7 makes allowances for external factors which can affect battery life.

Thus, the answer to your question:

> how can i take into consideration battery internal leakage current into my calculation?

You do this by multiplying by 0.7.

Answer (score 4):

As the footnote there says, "The factor of 0.7 makes allowances for external factors which can affect battery life." Presumably this estimate is meant to include a number of factors that will decrease the ideal estimated runtime, such as inefficiencies in buck/boost regulators, and losses from running at higher currents than the standard discharge current used for the nominal capacity rating (typically C/5 for Li-on and C/20 for lead-acid) - see [Peukert's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peukert's_law).

But you can typically compute much more accurate runtime estimates if you know the current rate(s) for your device. Then you can use the appropriate discharge curves in the battery's datasheet, and combine that with the efficiency curves for your buck / boost converter.